# Unable to fetch all fields from mongo document

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I want to fetch all the fields from a mongo document and also want to calculate the length of the specific document or document object.
My mongo document looks like :-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a80b0521fd923fd908a7f8"),
    "qus0" : "question 0",
    "qus0_count" : 0,
    "qus1" : "question 1",
    "qus1_count" : 0,
    "qus2" : "question 2",
    "qus2_count" : 0,
    "qus10" : "question 10",
    "qus10_count" : 0
}
```

Now I am using query to fetch data and it gives me only:

> `db.test.findOne({"_id": ObjectId("58a80b0521fd923fd908a7f8")});`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a80b0521fd923fd908a7f8"),
    "qus0_count" : 0,
    "qus1_count" : 0,
    "qus2_count" : 0,
    "qus10_count" : 0
}
```

and I am expecting :-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a80b0521fd923fd908a7f8"),
    "qus0" : "question 0",
    "qus0_count" : 0,
    "qus1" : "question 1",
    "qus1_count" : 0,
    "qus2" : "question 2",
    "qus2_count" : 0,
    "qus10" : "question 10",
    "qus10_count" : 0
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a collection with a schema following your example and was able to use findOne to acquire all elements of a document:

```
> db.test.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a80b0521fd923fd908a7f8"),
    "qus0" : "question 1",
    "qus0_count" : 0,
    "qus10" : "question 10",
    "qus10_count" : 0
}
> db.test.findOne({"_id": ObjectId("58a80b0521fd923fd908a7f8")});
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a80b0521fd923fd908a7f8"),
    "qus0" : "question 1",
    "qus0_count" : 0,
    "qus10" : "question 10",
    "qus10_count" : 0
}
```

Could you please edit your question with queries as above to help debug?

To answer your question about finding the size of documents, you can use Object.bsonsize():

```
> Object.bsonsize(db.test.findOne({"_id": ObjectId("58a80b0521fd923fd908a7f8")}));
99
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your request made on the client or the server ?

If it is on the client, make sure you published all the fields of your collection with the Meteor.publish function located in the server.

This will publish only some fields:

```
Meteor.publish('test', () => {
  return Test.find({}, {
    fields: {
      qus0_count: 1,
      qus1_count: 1,
      qus2_count: 1,
      qus10_count: 1,
    },
  });
});
```

This will publish all the fields:

```
Meteor.publish('test', () => {
  return Test.find({});
});
```